# Install Vundle plugin without Git Clone command

Tags: git, vim, vundle

I am at my company's network and it isn't possible for me to run commands such as `wget` or `git` on my console. I need to install Vundle plugin for Vim editor. All the installation I found says i need to do this

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

As this is not possible for me. I tried to download the `.zip` and copy it to `.vim/bundle/` directly but this does not seem to work.

Are they any alternatives to install the plugin ?

Comment: https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/blob/master/doc/vundle.txt#L226

Comment: You realize that Vundle.vim requires Git, right? Even if you managed to install it, without Git, you won't be able to use it to install plugins...

Comment: Plugins are not hard enough to install that you absolutely need a plugin manager. Just install your plugins manually.

Comment: [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) could be used manage your plugins in this case.

Comment: Did you actually unzip the zip file, or merely copy it to .vim/bundle? It should work if you unzip it there. After that, you would need to also download and unzip zip files of other plugins you wish to install; and then use the `file://` syntax romainl pointed to.